# Need vm timezone to be different than platform running on

Tags: virtualbox

My company just moved the servers across the US.  Opposite side from users.
What comes across the wire is the adjusted time.
Example:

```
database returns 01-Sep-2013 00:00:00.000 the we web app.
Accross the wire 31-Aug-2013 22:00:00.000
```

to code and test my fix I either need development deployment system in the mid west (very doubtful) or a way to change the timezone for my executing VM.

I see there are ways to break link by using UTC.  However I don't want to use UTC.  I want my vm to appear to be in one of the various US timezones.  Not sure what switching timezones does to oracle installs but will have to cross that problem.

Thoughts anyone solve this problem???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VM's date is based off of the physical computers HW clock.
If you need the VM to be some date in the past.  Adjust the the clock backwards, start the VM.
If you need to change the VM's time zone.

changing timezone is dependent on specific vm.  I am using centos.  Find desired timezone in /usr/share/zoneinfo.

```
mv  /etc/localtime /etc/localtime.orig
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/XXXXXX/YYY /etc/localtime
```

Not sure if you have to reboot.  Unfortunately there is not easy way to say I want the vm to suddenly be in another time zone.